# Are Transaction Pool and Transaction Queue the same thing?

Tags: transactions, transaction-pool

Was going through documentation of Substrate. I came across transaction lifecycle. https://docs.substrate.io/learn/transaction-lifecycle/

I'm confused about one line it which says

> "The transaction pool only deals with the validity of the transaction
> and the ordering of valid transactions placed in a transaction queue."

This poses a question

**Are transaction pool and transaction queue two different things?**

If yes how are they related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

In order for transactions to be included in the transaction pool and finally be included in a block they need to be validated and they need to be in a place, that place is the transaction queue.

Comment: Can you point to the Official documentation / Piece of code in substrate framework for better understanding?

Comment: @ShindeArjun sure, https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_transaction_pool/struct.BasicPool.html,  and https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_transaction_pool/struct.Pool.html